# Old to new molding transition

Tags: flooring, trim, baseboard

[image]

Picture shows corner of opening between kitchen (on left) and living room (on right). You can see that edge of laminate floor in living room doesn't go under base board(blue) but hidden by quarter round(red). I recently installed new floor (yellow) in kitchen area.

I am going to be installing new baseboard on top of kitchen floor, my question is, height of new  baseboard won't match with height of living room baseboard. Is that ok ? I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136096/mismatched-baseboards-tie-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with the height of the kitchen baseboard being a little lower, then you could cut a strip off the bottom of the kitchen baseboard so when it rests on the tile, its height matches the lounge baseboard.

You can then mitre the right end to make a neat finish with the lounge. If the baseboard ends here then the left end can be mitred as shown here https://youtu.be/dX2tVUg9r8I or https://youtu.be/8UlntpiHB8k